# Dummit and Foote page 512 claim

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, proof-explanation

Dummit and Foote Abstract Algebra page 512

Given any field F and any polynomial $p(x)\in F[x]$ one can ask a similar question: does there exist an extension K of F containing a solution of the equation $p(x)=0$
***Note we may assume here that the polynomial p(x) is irreducible*** in F[x] since a root of any factor of p(x) is certainly a root of p(x) itself

I am having trouble with the bold part. 
I understand that a root of a factor will also be a root of the polynomial, but I don't understand why we can assume p(x) is irreducible.

Any explanation of this would be great. Thanks.

Comment: A field containing a root of an irreducible factor of $p(x)$ is a field containing a root of $p(x)$, as desired. So it suffices to solve the problem for the case of $p(x)$ irreducible. Generally if $P$ is a predicate and $P(f)\Rightarrow P(fg)$ for all $g$ then to show $P(f)$ is true for all $f$ it suffices to show it true for all irreducible $f.\,$ In your case $\,P(f):= f\,$ has a root is some extension field.

Comment: Ah I see that now, thanks @BillDubuque . I realised it was driving towards a point like that but couldn't quite put my finger on it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A field containing a root of an irreducible factor of $p(x)$ is a field containing a root of $p(x)$, as desired. Therefore it suffices to solve the problem for the case of $p(x)$ irreducible.

Generally, if $\,S\subset F[x]^*\,$ is closed under multiplication then $\,S= F[x]^*\!\iff S$ contains every irreducible (and every unit), i.e. the  monoid $\,F[x]^*$ is *generated* by its irreducibles (and units).

In your case $S$ is the set of polynomials having a root in some extension field, which is clearly closed under multiplication since if $f(x)$ has a root in $K$ so too does $f(x)g(x)$.